# virtually locally solvable

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is locally solvable if all finitely generated subgroups are
solvable.

A group $G$ is virtually locally solvable if it has a locally solvable
subgroup of the finite index.

My question is:

$N\vartriangleleft G$ such that $G/N$ virtually locally solvable $\Rightarrow G$
virtually locally solvable?

Comment: You must make some assumptions on $N$, otherwise it is clearly false.

Comment: is it clearly false? Why?

Comment: Take $N$ to be some ugly group and consider $G\cong G/N\times N$.

Comment: It is clearly flase because you can take $N=G$ for any $G$; then $G/N$ is certainly virtually locally solvable: it's even solvable! But there is no reason why this would imply that $G$ is virtually locally solvable.

Comment: I think that if $N=\left\langle T;T\trianglelefteq G,T\text{ locally solvable }\right\rangle
$ is true (supposing that $G/N$ virtually locally solvable)